# Read a variable value in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am facing issue in reading the value of a variable from Header tag into LineDetail tag. I need to do conditional mapping based on this variable value. 
Could anyone please help me in resolving this?

Below is the sample of my transformation rule and I need to read the value of variable $varPOFlag in LineDetail tag.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
        <xsl:template match="Invoice">          
            <Invoice>       
            <Header>
                <!-- Read the PONumber if exists  -->
                <xsl:variable name="varHeaderPONumber">
                    <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="./Header/PONumber != ''">                       
                        <xsl:value-of select="./Header/PONumber" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable> 
                <!-- If PONumber does not exists in <Header> check at each lineItem level  -->
                <xsl:variable name="varLinePONumber">   
                    <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not(./Header/PONumber)" >
                        <xsl:for-each select="./LineDetail">                        
                            <xsl:if test="position()=1">                                
                                <xsl:value-of select="./PONumber" />                                                            
                            </xsl:if>                               
                        </xsl:for-each> 
                    </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>                   
                </xsl:variable>             
                <!--check if <Header.PONumber> matches with each <LineDetail.PONumber> -->
                <xsl:variable name ="var1212">
                    <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$varHeaderPONumber != ''">                                                  
                    <xsl:for-each select = "./LineDetail">                              
                        <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="./PONumber !=''" >                                      
                            <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test= "$varHeaderPONumber !=./PONumber">
                                <xsl:value-of select="'DoesNotMatch'"/>
                            </xsl:when>                                         
                            </xsl:choose>                                   
                        </xsl:when>                                 
                        </xsl:choose>                           
                    </xsl:for-each> 
                    </xsl:when> 
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable> 
                <!-- set the varPOFlag = 0 /1 if PONumber exists / does not exist -->
                <xsl:variable name="varPOFlag">
                    <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$varHeaderPONumber!='' or $varLinePONumber != ''">
                        <xsl:value-of select='1'/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select='0'/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>               
                </xsl:variable>             
            </Header>
            <LineDetail>
                    <!--Here I Need to read the value of variable $varPOFlag -->
                    <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$varPOFlag=0">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Number'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Description'"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
            </LineDetail>
            </Invoice>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is the sample output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice>
   <Header>      
      <PONumber />
      <ScanComments>One or more PO#s were detected at the Line Item level. Please select one PO# for the Header PO# value</ScanComments>
      <POFlag>1</POFlag>
      <DocumentSubType>PO-3Way</DocumentSubType>
      <BuyerName />
   </Header>
</Invoice>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of all those variables?  As it stands this stylesheet will always generate an empty `<Header/>` element as you're storing lots of stuff into variables but not actually writing anything to the result tree inside the `Header`

Comment: Hi Ian, The shared code snippet is just to derive the values of POFlag and PONumber. However, I have additional logic to map fields based on these variables.I am fine with PONumber, but facing issues in reading the value of varPOFlag in LineDetail section. Your suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables in XSLT are lexically scoped - you can't make reference to a variable that is declared inside one of your sibling elements.  But since a literal result element like `<Header>` doesn't change the context, it's safe to move all the variable declarations from inside the `Header` up a level or two - if you put them under `Invoice` then they will be accessible inside `LineDetail` as well as inside `Header`:

```
    <xsl:template match="Invoice">          
        <Invoice>       
            <!-- Read the PONumber if exists  -->
            <xsl:variable name="varHeaderPONumber">
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="./Header/PONumber != ''">                       
                    <xsl:value-of select="./Header/PONumber" />
                </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable> 
            <!-- If PONumber does not exists in <Header> check at each lineItem level  -->
            <xsl:variable name="varLinePONumber">   
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(./Header/PONumber)" >
                    <xsl:for-each select="./LineDetail">                        
                        <xsl:if test="position()=1">                                
                            <xsl:value-of select="./PONumber" />                                                            
                        </xsl:if>                               
                    </xsl:for-each> 
                </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>                   
            </xsl:variable>             
            <!--check if <Header.PONumber> matches with each <LineDetail.PONumber> -->
            <xsl:variable name ="var1212">
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$varHeaderPONumber != ''">                                                  
                <xsl:for-each select = "./LineDetail">                              
                    <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="./PONumber !=''" >                                      
                        <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test= "$varHeaderPONumber !=./PONumber">
                            <xsl:value-of select="'DoesNotMatch'"/>
                        </xsl:when>                                         
                        </xsl:choose>                                   
                    </xsl:when>                                 
                    </xsl:choose>                           
                </xsl:for-each> 
                </xsl:when> 
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable> 
            <!-- set the varPOFlag = 0 /1 if PONumber exists / does not exist -->
            <xsl:variable name="varPOFlag">
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$varHeaderPONumber!='' or $varLinePONumber != ''">
                    <xsl:value-of select='1'/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select='0'/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>               
            </xsl:variable>

            <Header>
            </Header>
            <LineDetail>
                <!--Here I Need to read the value of variable $varPOFlag -->
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$varPOFlag=0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Number'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Description'"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </LineDetail>
        </Invoice>
    </xsl:template>
```